# sharing states between two components with useReducer

Tags: reactjs

trying to share the states from one component to another: The state can be accessed from main component but it comes undefined when accessing from a new component
This is my reducer:

```
export const  tableReducer=(state = [], action)=> {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SELECTED_LIST':
            state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.payload));
            return state;
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

access it from a different file:

```
const [userList, usersDispatch] = useReducer(tableReducer, []);

useEffect(() => {
            const list = Object.keys(selectedRowIds).length > 0 ? selectedFlatRows.map(
                    d => d.original.email
                )
             : '';
            usersDispatch({ type: 'SELECTED_LIST', payload: list, });
    
        }, [selectedRowIds, selectedFlatRows]);
```

and in a new component:

```
const [userList] = useReducer(tableReducer);

    const deleteUsers = () => {
        console.log(userList)
    }
```

but here `console.log(userList)` it results to `undefined`

Comment: You can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to share state between components

Answer (score 23):

For Sharing of state between components, you can use Context API with useReducer.

Context API provides a neat way of providing state to child components without ending up with a prop drilling situation. It requires that a `Provider` is setup, which provides its values to any of its `Consumers`. Any component that is a child of the `Provider` can consume the context.

First a piece of context is created.

CustomContext.js

```
import React from 'react';

const CustomContext = React.createContext();

export function useCustomContext() {
  return React.useContext(CustomContext);
}

export default CustomContext;
```

We can define your reducer in a seperate file.

TableReducer.js

```
export const  tableReducer=(state = [], action)=> {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SELECTED_LIST':
            state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.payload));
            return state;
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

next is to implement the provider, and give it a value within a "Parent" component (A higher up component)

Parent.js

```
import CustomContext from './CustomContext'
import { tableReducer } from './TableReducer'

const ParentComponent = () => {

  const [userState, usersDispatch ] = React.useReducer(tableReducer, []);

  const providerState = {
    userState,
    usersDispatch
  }

  return (
    <CustomContext.Provider value={providerState} >
      <ChildComponent /> //Any component within here can access value by using useCustomContext();
    </CustomContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

now any component nested within <CustomContext.Provider></CustomContext.Provider> can access whatever is passed into "value" prop of the `Provider` which is your context state and the dispatch method.

The child component will look like this (I have ommited your state values and such..)

Child.js

```
import { useCustomContext }from './CustomContext'

const ChildComponent = (props) => {

    //your custom state variables and other methods


    const { userState, usersDispatch } = useCustomContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        const list = Object.keys(selectedRowIds).length > 0 ? selectedFlatRows.map(
                d => d.original.email
            )
         : '';
        usersDispatch({ type: 'SELECTED_LIST', payload: list, });

    }, [selectedRowIds, selectedFlatRows]);

  return(
      <div>your components dependent on selectedRowIds, selectedFlatRows<div>
   )

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't share the state with `useReducer` hook like you are trying to. Each call to `useReducer` returns a new state that is managed using the reducer function passed to `useReducer` hook.

Just as each call to `useState` returns a different state, each call to `useReducer` returns a different state. Two `useReducer` calls can't share the same state.

To share the state, you can use one of the following options:

- [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- [React-Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)
- Pass the state from parent component to child component using props

Answer (score 6):

@Gandzal is correct but I found it was lacking a typscript version and also today createContext requieres a default parameter. This came up as one of the top answers on google so I thought I would share.

I setup my solution like this:

**Custom context**:

```
import React, {Dispatch} from 'react';
import {StateType, Action} from './reducer'

interface IContextProps {
  state: StateType;
  dispatch:Dispatch<Action>
}

const CustomContext = React.createContext({} as IContextProps);

export function useCustomContext() {
  return React.useContext(CustomContext);
}

export default CustomContext;
```

**Note StateType and Action:**

```
export type StateType = {
  items: Array<DataItems>;
  date: Date;
};

export type Action = {
  type: ActionKind;
  payload: DataItems;
};
```

**reducer:**

```
export const reducer = (state: StateType, action: Action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  let newArray: Array<DataItems> = [];
   switch (type) {
    case ActionKind.Checked:
      newArray = state.items.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        checked: item.id === payload.id ? true : item.checked,
      }));
      return {
        ...state,
        items: newArray,
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**App.tsx:**

```
import { reducer, initalState } from 'Shared/Reducer/reducer';
import CustomContext from 'Shared/Reducer/CustomContext';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initalState);

  const providerState = {
    state,
    dispatch,
  };

  return (
    <CustomContext.Provider value={providerState}>
      <main role="main">
       // your components
      </main>
    </CustomContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And one of your components:

```
import { useCustomContext } from 'Shared/Reducer/CustomContext';

    export const MyComp: React.FC<MyType> = (props) => {
      const { data} = props;
      const { state, dispatch } = useCustomContext(); --- Your state and dispatch here
      return (
        <div>
          // your component
        </div >
      );
    }
```